# Delete row view from custom list using base Adapter solution

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview

Hi I can not delete a row from list View i don't know how to delete it i search a lot from Internet i try out many examples but yet i can't solve the issue . when i click the hldr.delete button the complete row of list View delete from the list solution pls.

**PlaceOrder Activity**

```
public class PlaceOrder extends Activity {

    String [] pIds; 
    String [] pNames; 
    String [] pPrizes; 
    static ListView lv;
    ImageView bck;
    String [] listImages;
    String food_id;
    String userdata[];
    Intent i;
    TextView totalprze;
    float tprize;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_order);

        lv=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.cart_list);
        bck=(ImageView) findViewById(R.id.placeholder_bg_btn);
        totalprze =(TextView) findViewById(R.id.place_order_price);

        i=new Intent(this,Menu.class);

        bck.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                 Bundle bundle=new Bundle();

                    //bundle.putStringArray("images", ListImages);
                    bundle.putString("food_id", food_id);
                    bundle.putStringArray("images", listImages);
                    bundle.putStringArray("userData",userdata);
                    i.putExtras(bundle);
                    startActivity(i);
            }
        });


        if(this.getIntent().getExtras()!=null)
        {

         Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();

         pIds=b.getStringArray("pId");
         pNames=b.getStringArray("PName");
         pPrizes=b.getStringArray("pPrize");
         userdata=b.getStringArray("userData");
         tprize=b.getFloat("totalprize");


         food_id=b.getString("food_id");
         listImages=b.getStringArray("images");
         String prz=Float.toString(tprize);
         totalprze.setText("$"+prz);
         lv.setAdapter(new cartAdapter(PlaceOrder.this, pIds, pNames, pPrizes,userdata));

         pIds=null;
         pNames=null;
         pPrizes=null;
       }
    }
        public void onBackPressed() {
         pIds=null;
         pNames=null;
         pPrizes=null;
        }

}
```

**CartAdapter**

```
public class cartAdapter  extends BaseAdapter{

     String [] pIdz;
     String [] pNamz;
     String [] pPrizs;
     String [] userData;
    // List<String> imges;
     Context context;
    // private ShopingCartHelper obj;

     private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
     JSONArray jCat = null;
     int count=0;
     ProgressDialog pDialog;


     public cartAdapter(PlaceOrder ctx,
             String[] pIds,String[] pNams, String[] pprise,String [] userdata) {

         pIdz=pIds;
         pNamz=pNams;

         context=ctx;
         pPrizs=pprise;
         userData=userdata;

         inflater = ( LayoutInflater )context.
                         getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub

     }

        @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if(pIdz==null){
                Toast.makeText(context, "There is issue with net connection.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //Intent i=new Intent(context,WelcomeActivity.class);
                //context.startActivity(i);
                return count ;
            }else{
                return pIdz.length;
            }

        }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return position;

    }

    public class holder{
         TextView pid;
         TextView pname;
         TextView pprise;
         Button delete;
         ListView lv;

    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       final  holder hldr=new holder();
        View rowView = null;
        Bitmap bitmap = null;



          rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.place_order_item_list, null);
          hldr.pid=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_id);
          hldr.pname=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_name);
          hldr.pprise=(TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.item_price);
          hldr.delete=(Button) rowView.findViewById(R.id.delete);   
          hldr.pid.setText(pIdz[position]);
          hldr.pname.setText(pNamz[position]);
          hldr.pprise.setText(pPrizs[position]);

          /* convertView.setTag(hldr);
          hldr.delete.setTag(hldr);*/
          //
          //  Picasso.with(context).load(imgs[position]).into(hldr.img);
          hldr.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                // rowView.remove(position); //removing from your List
                //Toast.makeText(context, "Delete",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                int pid=Integer.parseInt(hldr.pid.getText().toString());
                //Toast.makeText(context, "pid"+pid, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                new ShopingCartHelper(context).delProduct(pid);
                 //PlaceOrder.lv.removeViewAt(position);

                notifyDataSetChanged();

            }
        });
           rowView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
//              // TODO Auto-generated method stub
//               cartAdapter.this.pIdz.remove[position];

            //  Toast.makeText(context, "hi",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
         return rowView;

        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove anything from an array - they're always fixed length. Once you've created an array of length 3, that array will always have length 3. And if you want to delete from the listview the array which you are used should be dynamic(Adding & Deleting). So make the `pIdz; pNamz;pPrizs;userData` into some Modal Object, and prepare the list of Modal Objects and pass it to **adapter** and make the life easier

You'd be better off with a List, e.g. an ArrayList:

```
hldr.delete.setTag(position);
hldr.delete.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int position = (int)v.getTag();                
            list.remove(position);
            notifyDataSetChanged();

        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

First.

You should make a object that stores all your different strings instead of using multiple arrays for each value.

Ej:

```
class MyClass
{
    String id;
    String name
    String price;

    public MyClass(String id, String name, String price)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
    }
}
```

That way you wouldnt have to delete the position of each of the arrays.

And finally to answer your question, just delete the value of position you want to delete for each of the arrays.

Since they are Array and not ArrayList you will need to recreate it with the correct new dimension (Note it will be much easier with ArrayList).

Then just call notifyDataSetChanged() on your Adapter class.

Hope this helps.